# Change Content of a Button from c#behind-code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

My question is about wp7. I'm trying to change the Content of a Button in c# behind-code, after user clicks it. In particular I want to change the Fill property of my three Path elements, that are inside a grid("GraphGrid"). This grid is the Content of the Button itself.
Here is XAML code about the Button:

```
<Button.Content>
  <Grid x:Name="GraphGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
   VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
   <Path x:Name="Path"
      Data="M 0,0 0,80 20,80 20,0Z"
  Stroke="Black"
  Fill="Black"
  StrokeThickness="0"/>
<Path
  Data="M 25,20 25,80 45,80 45,20Z"
  Stroke="Black"
  Fill="Black"
  StrokeThickness="0"/>
<Path
  Data="M 50,40 50,80 70,80 70,40Z"
  Stroke="Black"
  Fill="Black"
  StrokeThickness="0"/>
```

I tried to use keys(such as x:Name...) to refer to my Xaml element in c# behind code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ViralShah Spam spam spam, http://bit.ly/UOJqxi Link redirects me to: http://cloudtweak.wordpress.com/lifetime-membership/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="GraphGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Path x:Name="Path"
      Data="M 0,0 0,80 20,80 20,0Z"
  Stroke="Black"
  Fill="Black"
  StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="path1"
     Data="M 25,20 25,80 45,80 45,20Z"
     Stroke="Black"
     Fill="Black"
     StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="Path2"
     Data="M 50,40 50,80 70,80 70,40Z"
     Stroke="Black"
     Fill="Black"
     StrokeThickness="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        path1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
        Path2.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
        Path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it in XAML without any codebehind:

```
<Button>
        <Button.Content>
            <Grid x:Name="GraphGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Path x:Name="Path"
          Data="M 0,0 0,80 20,80 20,0Z"
      Stroke="Black"
      Fill="Black"
      StrokeThickness="0"/>
                    <Path  x:Name="Path2"
         Data="M 25,20 25,80 45,80 45,20Z"
         Stroke="Black"
         Fill="Black"
         StrokeThickness="0"/>
                    <Path  x:Name="Path3"
         Data="M 50,40 50,80 70,80 70,40Z"
         Stroke="Black"
         Fill="Black"
         StrokeThickness="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard >
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" From="Black" To="Red"></ColorAnimation>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" From="Black" To="Yellow"></ColorAnimation>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" From="Black" To="Blue"></ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>

                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

        </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```